# Is it a good idea to write a view to expose a REST API

Tags: java, rest, view

1. Is it s good practice to write a complex view joining 2-3 tables and then create a model and then expose it as a RESTful service.

OR

2. Expose individual services and let the consumers apply the logic of combining them or use them however they seem fit.

I am leaning towards 2nd one because the view can be complex and we do not want to maintain it going forward. But i would like what the general view or thoughts are about this approach

Comment: Database, as programming, is not exact science. You have to choose between data calculation and business logic and mantainability. 
I usually prefer keep all logic in OOP environment since especially complex queries are hard as hell to mantain. Consider how could be on the other hand splitting logic in a java pattern lifecycle; that should be a different story for sure, especially if well written and documented. Rest layer is useful to separate your business model so both approach are irrilevant under that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

THe first approach is good enough if the view entity will be exactly what the client needs.
Second approach will be better if you want to allow the client to use the joined data separately. I think in your case the first approach is good and **the view isn't harder than a table to maintain.
 You will have to write more code in the service/controller/dao layer if you choose to serve the entities separately and that won't be easier for maintenance.**

Answer (score 0):

It might be that providing the separate endpoints will be needed anyway, so (not being able to see what you're doing) I'd guess you won't have so much an either/or choice but rather an "is it worth providing this extra view of the data? choice.

In the long run, too, your customers may curse you if it's a pain to collect all the required data through multiple requests.

I'd suggest you benchmark the view (time the round trip from the application to the database) and compare it with the time for the simpler queries *plus* the added time for processing the two extra requests to your application ... it's possible the combined resource usage for the multiple client requests outweighs the saving from not doing a "complex" query.

I have to ask ... is joining three tables that big of a deal? Because if it's just a simple join with a couple of foreign keys, three tables isn't particularly complex; and if the query *is* complex, wouldn't you still have to do about as much work to answer the followup queries when the client requests the rest of the data? Without the benefit of doing it all in one go, warm caches everywhere on the database server, and so on.